# C++ Reading in wrong values from a file

Tags: c++

My data file contains the following numbers to be read in

```
/*
111
100.00
200.00
50.00
222
200.00
300.00
100
*/
```

but after the while loop reads in customerNumber as 100 when it should be 111, it get's the values for everything else wrong also.  Such as beginningBalance reading as

```
//-9255963134931783000000000000000000000000.00
```

and everything else seems to be reading the same value. I'm just learning about files so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int customerNumber;
double beginningBalance, purchase, payments, financeCharge, endingBalance;
ifstream inputFile;
ofstream outputFile;

inputFile.open("BeginningBalance.dat");
cout<<"Cust No | Beginning Bal | Finance Charge | Purchases | Payments | Ending Balance"<<endl;

while (inputFile >> customerNumber);
    {
     inputFile >> beginningBalance;
     inputFile >> purchase;
     inputFile >> payments;
     financeCharge = beginningBalance * .01;
     endingBalance = beginningBalance + purchase + financeCharge - payments;
     cout<<setw(5)<<customerNumber<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<"        "<<beginningBalance<<"        "<<financeCharge<<"          "<<purchase<<"       "<<payments<<"       "<<endingBalance<<endl;
    }


system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try removing the `/*` and `*/` and see what happens?

Comment: Are the `/*` and `*/` actually in the data file?

Comment: Never use doubles for financial data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing the semicolon from after your while loop condition and see if that fixes it.

So change

```
while (inputFile >> customerNumber);
```

to

```
while (inputFile >> customerNumber)
```

The way it is now, it does nothing until it eats up all the data from the file, *then* does the stuff inside the `{ ... }`, and the file reads you do in there are already at EOF so they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

The /* at the beginning of the file is corrupting your data. Either remove the /* or account for them by reading in two junk characters before your read your customer number.

Also you have a semicolon after your while loop statement that you need to remove.